# Rails calling API causes uninitialized constant error in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using the RMeetup gem to pull data from meetup.com. In development mode, I can feature this code in my controller, model or helper with no issues:

```
RMeetup::Client.api_key = "matt's key"
RMeetup::Client.fetch(:groups, :lat => @user.latitude, :lon => @user.longitude")
```

But when I try to deploy, Heroku tells me:

```
app[web.1]: NameError (uninitialized constant RMeetup::Client):
```

I'm a novice on Rails, and I don't know how to fix this problem. I've tried creating a new RMeetup model to maybe better house this information and fix the issue, but Rails tells me:

```
The name 'RMeetup' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.
```

The RMeetup gem is not located exclusively in the dev section of my gemfile. Complicating the matter, I don't actually save any of the data I receive from Meetup.com until a user fills out a form. So I don't have a natural place to build a model off the results from RMeetup fetch operations. I currently do it in a helper or controller.

So why does my local dev have no problem with "RMeetup::Client" but Heroku does, and how can I fix it?

**As requested, here is also the Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rMeetup'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  gem 'puma'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.0.0'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Comment: What's in your Gemfile?

Comment: See above. I've also tried putting rmeetup in production group, but I am still getting uninitialized constant. Is it something else I'm doing wrong there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
 gem 'rMeetup', require: 'rmeetup'
```

in your Gemfile

Comment: Wow, that worked. I've never come across that before. Any chance you can point to me any documentation of why this works so I can avoid it in the future?

Comment: by default rails requires the same file as you mention in Gemfile. For example you mention gem 'rMeetup' - so rails try to find file 'rMeetup.rb' but cannot. Look at source code of gem https://github.com/Jberlinsky/rmeetup/blob/master/lib/rmeetup.rb - there is rmeetup.rb which should be required - if required file is different of gem name you need add param 'require: <filename' to gem method in Gemfile. Look at bundler documentation: http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html